# MySQL query advice required

Tags: mysql

I have the following table representing products and their attributes/properties. I need to write a query that will get the `value` of the property named `Insert Style` for products where the `First Choice Material` is `Gold`.

[image]

I got this far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM shop_product_properties
WHERE name = 'Insert Size'
AND product_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT product_id
    FROM shop_product_properties
    WHERE ((LOWER(name) = 'first choice material'
    AND value = 'Aluminium') AND (LOWER(name) = 'insert style' AND value = 'CCGT'))
);
```

Comment: What's the query you tried to run?

Comment: I'm pretty stumped as to where to start with it if i'm honest.

Comment: But i've kicked it off.

Comment: `LOWER(name)` will never be `'First choice material'`

Comment: Do a select where name=insert style and value=gold and then inner join this query with the same table on productid=productid

Comment: Can you show what you want the query to return?

Comment: "get all value with name Insert Style where First Choice Material = Gold" -this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @bfavaretto: yes it will. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f54a1/2

Comment: @Quassnoi Hm, right, it depends on the collation used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to write a query that will get all value with name Insert Style

So start with that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM shop_product_properties
WHERE name = 'Insert Style';
```

> where First Choice Material = Gold AND they have the same product_id

Then introduce a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM shop_product_properties
WHERE name = 'Insert Style'
AND product_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT product_id
    FROM shop_product_properties
    WHERE name = 'First Choice Material'
    AND value = 'Gold'
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecfb4/1

Comment: I think you are on the right lines. Although it's not working for me atm.

Comment: It doesn't fail it just returns no results.

Comment: It should also be selecting distinct `value` of name = `Insert Style`

Comment: Got it working now. With your code example helping alot! Thanks so much.

Comment: Also I just edited it to be an even bigger query. Though it's not yet working does it look feasible to you?

Comment: I guess not actually doesn't make sense.

Comment: No, if you need to check two properties, you need a join with another instance of the table. Could you update my sql fiddle with more data? Then I could try further later.

Comment: The URL updates when you do so. My old URL still shows my original data. Anyway, I'll have to be away from the computer for a few hours, will check back later, okay?

Comment: That looks extremely close. I will review when I am home later today! thanks so much!