# MySQL join on the same table twice

Tags: mysql

I am trying to think how to solve this query with joins but am currently struggling.

The best way to understand what I am trying to do is look at the original query I wrote which obviously neither works nor would ever work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM shop_product_properties
WHERE name = 'Insert Size'
    AND product_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT product_id
    FROM shop_product_properties
        WHERE ((LOWER(name) = 'first choice material'
        AND value = 'Aluminium') AND (LOWER(name) = 'insert style' AND value = 'CCGT'))
);
```

I realise I probably need to solve this with joins on the same table. I am just unclear as to where to start with it.

Comment: I think you're still getting help with this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904865/mysql-query-advice-required  is it not the same thing?

Comment: Another level of complexity on top of that one now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  spp.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  product_id
        FROM    shop_product_properties
        WHERE   (name, value) = ('first_choice_material', 'Aluminum')
                OR
                (name, value) = ('insert style', 'CCGT')
        GROUP BY
                product_id
        HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
        ) q
JOIN    shop_product_properties spp
ON      (spp.product_id, spp.name) = (q.product_id, 'Insert Size')
```

Make sure you have a unique index on `(name, product_id)` for it to work fast and correctly.

Comment: Thanks alot for providing this answer. I will test it when I get home!